# How to get Excel to read negative numbers as 'real' instead of 'absolute'

Tags: excel

I have this IF/AND statement in a column (the variables being different cells):

```
=IF(i<0,(n-x),z)
```

When `i` is negative, excel is still reading it as a positive, so it's `z` no matter what.

I've tried switching the True/False statements around, and changing the format of the numbers.

Comment: Here is a better example: =IF(H25<0,(C25-E25),D25)

Comment: Perhaps the `i` cells have text that looks like numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Excel treats *Text* values as positive, even if the cell starts with the minus sign:

[image]

If this is the case, then base the **IF** on the first character in the string.